Are there other proposed translations of "aelfheres" in Beowulf than a name?
Am looking at the online Beowulf site, and wonder about "aelfheres" that is translated as a name.


XXXVI
WIGlaf wæs haten,    Weoxstanes sunu,
leoflic lindwiga,    leod Scylfinga,
mæg Ælfheres.

But it looks like the "ae" is lower case in the manuscript? Are there any other proposed translations than "friend of Aelfhere"?
Clarification: I am wondering if anybody has proposed any other translation than "friend/relative of [unknown person not mentioned anywhere else]."

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://literature.stackexchange.com/

@user66974 Nah it belongs here.

Does this document ever have upper case Æ or is it just written the same as æ ?

This is no answer but it looks like the only thing capitalized in the manuscript are the beginning of sentences. words that have been identified as proper names are capitalized in the print version. 'Ælfhere' is only mentioned once in Beowulf but may actually refer to an actual person (so at least the word is a known name of the time). The parallelism highly suggests that it is 'a kinsman of [someone]'.

Did you yourself have a suggestion for an alternate reading of the word? Was there some motivation for thinking maybe it's something else?

Why are you expecting names to be in uppercase?  That's a modern convention.  Names in the manuscript are in lowercase when the name isn't in a position that gets "decorated" with a capital.   It's a genitive there, BTW.

From a desultory google search, that phrase is only ever translated as 'friend/relative of Ælfhere'. There may well be other attempts (older print ones) that do something different. Do you have any hint as to why you may think it is something other than that guys name?

Names in Old English manuscripts are typically spelled without leading capital. Nothing unusual in that. It's a man's name in genitive case. mæg higelaces  "kinsman of Hygelac" occurs a half-dozen times in the poem (though the spelling of Hygelac isn't always exactly the same).
Compare hroþgar here:

Cropped image taken from
https://blogs.bl.uk/.a/6a00d8341c464853ef017d40e0bd66970c-500wi
at https://blogs.bl.uk/digitisedmanuscripts/2013/02/beowulf-online.html
[P.S. I haven't read through the British Library's Terms and Conditions and would prefer not to copy the page in its entirety here.]

Bingo-bang! ... I think. :)

From an MIT anonymous translation in 2003

WIGLAF his name was, Weohstan's son, - Wiglaf wæs haten Weoxstanes sunu,
linden-thane loved, the lord of Scylfings - leoflic lindwiga, leod Scylfinga,
Aelfhere's kinsman………………………………. – mæg Ælfheres

As far as I can see, this is accurate.
See also BEOWULF: diacritically-marked text and facing translation
Edit to add aelf is a variant of ielf/ylf = Mod. Eng. "elf"; here = "army".
However, at the time that Beowulf was written, all such meaning had been removed and it is pointless to translate the name.
The capitalisation is irrelevant - in the day it was more a matter of style than significance.

It's on Wikipedia: Ælfhere (died in 983) was Ealdorman of Mercia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86lfhere,_Ealdorman_of_Mercia But no final s.

Ælfhere is not an uncommon Anglo-Saxon name. See the ONOMASTICON ANGLO SAXONICUM by W.G. Searle (Cambridge, 1897).

@Lambie The "s" is the Saxon genitive.

I know that. Thanks though.

I don’t think we can really say that “all such meaning had been removed”. Certainly, the meaning would have been disassociated from the name and in normal life it would just be that guy Ælfhere, but the meaning would still be as transparently available as when someone is called Rock or April or Rowan nowadays. It’s not like someone called Elmer, where the original meaning ‘noble fame’ is now completely lost and only available through an etymological lookup.

Do we know Ælfhere was a common name in sixth century Sweden?

And we don't really know when it was 'written down' do we. We know when that copy was made, that we happen to have.

@TomasBy - See TimR's comment above. Also, if you are concerned, look at the link by Lambie and see how many of one Ælfhere's family had Ælf as the first syllable.

I'm not sure it's relevant. The name needs to fit into the story, which takes place some centuries earlier, mainly in Sweden, not into the context of the copying much later.

Would it matter, if the name were common or not? If you think it does, I would encourage you to include the details in an answer. (I am puzzled by the idea of a character's name "fitting in" to a story - can you expand?

In J.R.R. Tolkien’s prose translation of Beowulf, those lines he translated  this way:

In one alone of them the heart was moved with grief. Kinship may nothing set aside in virtuous mind. Wiglaf was he called, Wihstan’s son, that fair warrior beneath his shield, a lord of Scylfing race of Ælfhere’s line.  He saw his liege-lord beneath his vizored helm of war in torment of heat. He remembered then those favours which Beowulf had granted to him, the rich dwelling-place of the Wægmundings, and all the landed rights which his father before had held.

As you see, the original mæg ælfheres became Ælfhere’s line. At no point did Tolkien ever translate ælfhere into anything that was not clearly that same personal name.
For the curious, that particular text can be found on page 89 of the 2014 edition of Beowulf: A Translation and Commentary by J.R.R. Tolkien (posthumous), which was edited and published by his son Christopher. The original translation work was done a century ago sometime over the years 1920–1926.
